# Вывод больших дробей из базы

Tags: php, mysql

В базе есть запись со значением **0.0000000500**

При выводе этого значения в скрипте получаю: **5.0E-8**

В базе тип столбца: **decimal(65,10)**

Каким образом вывести значения из базы в таком виде как оно записано в базе?

Comment: MySQL отдаст значение ровно в той форме, какая определена типом данных поля, если не указано иное явным или неявным приведением типа. Перевод  в научную нотацию - самодеятельность PHP. Если не нравится - используйте явное форматирование значения к нужному формату. В Php [функция форматирования чисел](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php) - имеется.

Comment: @Akina можно пожалуйста пример?

Comment: Примеры есть в мануале.

Comment: Как вариант можно привести значение к строке: `$num = "'$num'"`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте number_format и подставляйте значение в первый аргумент, во второй кол-во знаков после точки, которые хотите отобразить.

Пример кода:

```
echo number_format('5.0E-8', 10);
```

Результат:

> 0.0000000500